# Is it okay to delete CWM backups after copying them to my pc?

Tags: rom, clockworkmod-recovery

Recently, I installed CWM (Rom Manager) and a custom recovery in my Xperia SP. Then I went to Rom Manager and pressed 'Backup Current ROM' which took me to a screen that backed up everything. Then I used `adb pull /mnt/shell/emulated/clockworkmod/backup` to copy that backup into my PC. Now, the copied files in my PC are:[image]

Now,

1. First thing, from what you see, can you tell me if the backup is complete (it is about 2 GB)? Well, [this](http://pastebin.com/wy0yQvh9) is the content of the recovery.log file.
2. Can I delete the backup present in my phone(because it is occupying a
   large amount of space ~2 GB)? Or should I keep it there. I have
   heard of mysterious evil things like **bricking, bootloops** etc.
   (which I am REALLY scared of). And in many places I've found that
   the best way to recover from those scary things is to use the backup
   of the ROM. Now, please **tell me that if such a disaster happens to
   my phone, can I transfer the files from my PC to the phone or do
   they need to be in the phone for me to be able to recover from the
   disaster?**

Answer (score 1):

You can theoretically delete them without hesitation after moving, but do keep in mind that CWM depends on file integrity checks like MD5 to see if your images have not been modified since the day you took a Nandroid backup. There are some cases when phone-to-PC transfers  ruin the MD5 signature<sup>1</sup> and therefore prevent CWM from restoring the Nandroid backup in the future.

If you do every step in ROM installation exactly as said in the instructions listed on your ROM webpage and you're not going to do anything daring after successful installation, chances are you're not going to need that Nandroid backup anyway. But it's always better to be safe.

---

<sup>1</sup> speaking from experience